Why process.exit fails to stop execution of code
I currently have a file called shellScript.sh that has the following two lines
node firstJavascriptFile.js
node secondJavascriptFile.js

The contents of firstJavascriptFile.js are as follows:
console.log('starting first javascript file')
process.exit(1);

The contents of secondJavascriptFile.js are as follows:
console.log('starting second javascript file')
process.exit(0);

My goal is to code firstJavascriptFile.js in such a way that secondJavascriptFile.js will not be called when I run ./shellScript.sh. (obviously I can just not call secondJavascriptFile.js from shellScript.sh, but my actual task is a bit more complex and requires that I only change firstJavascriptFile.js - I have tried to distill what's necessary into this stack overflow question)
When I run ./shellScript.sh from the terminal the output is
starting first javascript file
starting second javascript file

However, I am trying to edit the process.exit call in firstJavascriptFile.js so that the code in secondJavascriptFile.js is not called when I run ./shellScript.sh i.e. I want the output to be:
starting first javascript file

I have also tried using process.exit(0) but this doesn't change anything. Is there any way I can stop the execution of secondJavascriptFile.js by only changing the contents of firstJavascriptFile.js?

process.exit terminates the current process, that is, the node process that's running that bit of JavaScript. Then the OS goes on with the sh file and run its second line, calling the second js file. What's missing is error handling in the sh file.

Are you looking for node firstJavascriptFile.js && node secondJavascriptFile.js?

process.exit() just ends the node process, it has no effect on the parent shell process.
The normal way to accomplish this is to have the shell check the exit status e.g.
node firstJavascriptFile.js && node secondJavascriptFile.js

If you can't change the shell script, you'll need to kill the parent from JavaScript:
console.log('starting first javascript file');
process.kill(process.ppid);
process.exit(1);

But this is generally a bad design, it assumes that the script will always be run from a context that needs to cancel everything after the script. Also, if the first script is called from a subshell, e.g.
variable=$(node firstJavascriptfile.js)

it will only kill the subshell, not the full shell.
